# EasyPHP could not connect to localhost (Port 8080)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost, easyphp

I have a problem with EasyPHP 5.3.9!
Apache and MySQL are working but when i click on: Administration, PhpMyAdmin or LocalWeb it open Google Chrome and the page says: Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8080
I have changed the string in configuration: Listen 127.0.0.1:8080 to 127.0.0.1:80 but with no results... i have tried everything.
I've download the TCPview and the ports 80 and 8080 are free... the firewall is closed etc...
I don't what to do :/ 
Any solution?
(Sry for my bad english)

Comment: if the ports are 'free', then you nothing bound to those ports listening for a connection. e.g. apache hasn't been started or is binding to a different port/ip set.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is your issue, but on Windows 8 (and probably Windows 7), EasyPHP does not run as admin when started causing most of the tools accessible from the system tray to fail. I got it to open Local Web by:

1. Stopping and exiting easyphp through the system tray.
2. Browsing to C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1
3. Right clicking on EasyPHP-12.1 and selecting Properties
4. Select the Compatibility tab and check the box Run this program as an administrator
5. Start EasyPHP again either from the icon or from the Start screen
6. Local Web and Administration now work for me.

Worked for me, but could be other issues.